# Tomcat7 fails to restart and log issue

Tags: centos, logging, tomcat7

I have a CentOS (`CentOS release 6.7 (Final)`) server running Tomcat7.  I ran some updates using `yum` and now Tomcat will not restart.

```
etc/rc.d/init.d/tomcat restart
Stopping tomcat:                                           [FAILED]
Starting tomcat:                                           [FAILED]
```

I have looked in `/etc/tomcat/logs/`, but there are no logs.  I would have a least expected `/etc/tomcat/logs/tomcat-initd.log` to be there.  Where else would Tomcat log to?

Comment: What OS are you using, CentOS7?

Comment: @ALex_hha  please see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where else would Tomcat log to?

Should be there

```
# rpm -ql tomcat | grep /var/log
/var/log/tomcat
/var/log/tomcat/catalina.out
```